# AngularJs Routing not working anymore. Address bar changes but view does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/iNG2DY3Wams48GxpI2KK?p=preview

I'm having an issue with routing.  It was working perfectly fine before.  I haven't changed anything in the script.js file.  Now it refuses to go a different page.  I have the partials(.html files) stored in partials/about.html etc

When I click on any links in the nav bar or the footer...the view doesn't change...it's stuck on the main page however the address bar has changed.

Thanks.

```
html ng-app="financeApp">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- CSS -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-    awesome.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css"/>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
<!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
<header>
<div class="wrap">
  <!-- logo -->

   <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" /></a>

       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"></a>
        </div>

        <ul class=" navbar-right">

             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

             <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>



        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>

<body>

<div ng-controller='mainController'>


<div back-img="img/02.png" >




</div>



</div>



<!-- Loading the Footer -->
 <div id="footer" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>


</div>

<!-- App JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.js"></script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"> </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this script.js file

```
var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', ['ngRoute']);

 // configure our routes
 financeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/main.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
});
```

Comment: sounds like maybe your server stopped. what does it say in the [console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)?

Comment: My server seems to be ok as  I can edit/delete stuff on the app and it shows when I refresh the page.  The only thing that doesn't work  is the links to different views.

Comment: missing a `/` in your `href`'s. Demo is worthless without including script dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code i have noticed that mainly

> " ng-view" attribute
>    is missing , "BODY" alignment  and all the tags are not clear rectify these issues and In plunker provide all the necessary file what your trying